# How to repeat each() without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below markup

```
<div class="main">
  <ul class="ajax-terms">
    <li id="app-105">Find Friends</li>
    <li id="app-107">Buy Tickets,Pay Cover Charges</li>
    <li id="app-114">Pre-purchase bottle service</li>
    <li id="app-117">Book VIP Services</li>
    <li id="app-120">Buy Merchandise</li>
    <li id="app-122">Toast Friends worldwide</li>
    <li id="app-125">Notify Services &amp; split the tab</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to add a class `myclass` from first `li` element with one after another.Let's say it is added on first `li` element then after 5 seconds it will be added to second `li` and it is removed from first `li`,then add to third `li` and remove it from second `li` then so on.When it reaches last `li`,it should again restart from first `li` so that cycle continues.

Currently my code is like:

```
  $('.main li').each(function(i, el) {

   setTimeout(function() {
       $(el).addClass('myclass');
     }, i * 3000);

     setTimeout(function() {
       $(el).removeClass('myclass');

     }, i * 3500);



});
```

Problems I am facing:

1) It is not repeating when it reaches last `li`.

2) It starts from second `li`, not first (may be some delay issue)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the purpose of those classes ?

Comment: class has some hover properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

```
var count=0;  // flag 
var len = $('.main li').length;  // Get the total length of the li to iterate the loop

    setInterval(function(){ // Execute a function in every 1 sec
        if(count === len){
            count = 0;  // Reset the flag to restart the loop
        }
        $('.main').find(".myclass").removeClass("myclass");  // Before adding the class, first find it and remove the class
        $('.main li').eq(count).addClass("myclass"); // eq(count) gives the specific li children where we want the class to be added
        count++;
    }, 1000);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/21woyf1f/)

Comment: It worked.But I didn't understand how it was looping all li's repeatedly.Any hints.

Answer (score 1):

Even though @SujataChanda has given an elegant approach using jQuery, the same can also be achieved using simple javascript. Here's the javascript approach to rotate the `myclass` class among several `li` elements,

```
// get the ids of all the li elements in an array
var idArray = ["app-105", "app-107", "app-114", "app-117", "app-120", "app-122", "app-125"];

// index is used to select particular id from the array
var index = 0;

// initially set the class attribute of first li
document.getElementById(idArray[index]).setAttribute("class", "myclass");

// with each rotation if the class attribute of current li element is set then it will 
// remove its class attribute, select the next li element in the sequence 
// and set its class attribute
function rotation(){
    if(document.getElementById(idArray[index]).hasAttribute("class")){
        document.getElementById(idArray[index]).removeAttribute("class");
        index = (index + 1) % 7;
        document.getElementById(idArray[index]).setAttribute("class", "myclass");
    }
}

// call rotation function in every 3 seconds
var everyInterval = setInterval(rotation, 3000);
```

**Edited:**

```
// in near future if you're going to add many li elements inside <ul class="ajax-terms"> 
// tag, then you should dynamically loop through each li element to get its id.
var lis = document.getElementsByClassName("ajax-terms")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");
var idArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; ++i){
    idArray[i] = lis[i].id;
}
```

And oh, I almost forgot, the `index` calculation inside `if` block will be like this,

```
index = (index + 1) % idArray.length;
```

Comment: That's good but more `li`s will be added automatically in future,then how can I grab those `li`s without array?

Comment: @Hiranya Yes, you can certainly do that. In that case you have to dynamically loop through each li element to get its id. Please see the **edited** section of my answer.

Comment: @Hiranya and oh, for the dynamic array `index` calculation will be different. I've also updated that in the **edited** section.